# Remove all elements except string from list

Tags: python

I have a list which looks like this `[[{a:7},"1",{x:0.25},"2"],[{y:0.25,x:1.5},"4"],[{y:-0.75},"3"]]` and i want to remove everything that isn't a string from the list while still keeping the "shape" of the list so the output should look like this `[["1", "2"], ["4"], ["3"]]`. How can i do this?

Comment: With a [filter](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) and the [type function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_type.asp) it should be relatively easy to achieve this. Try it with flat lists first. If you then have problems with nested list structures you can ask here more concrete questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create new list with required values, you can use list comprehension:

```
given = [[{a: 7}, "1", {x: 0.25}, "2"], [{y: 0.25, x: 1.5}, "4"], [{y: -0.75}, "3"]]
new_data = [[e for e in inner if isinstance(e, str)] for inner in given]
```

This means: "create new list of lists, where inner items are only string values".

If you need to modify given list inplace, the following should do:

```
given = [[{a: 7}, "1", {x: 0.25}, "2"], [{y: 0.25, x: 1.5}, "4"], [{y: -0.75}, "3"]]
for i, inner in enumerate(given):
    given[i] = [e for e in inner if isinstance(e, str)]
```

Using `pop` or `del` in such context is not advisable, because a) it changes list length during iteration (and is bug prone), and b) it is less efficient.

Comment: You should consider using basestring instead of str.

Comment: Really? I doubt that python2 compatibility is a concern in 2022 (at least until explicitly stated in question), and basestring was removed in 3.0...